# Creating 3 ZMQ PUB with using 1 SDR source

Tags: signal-processing, zeromq, gnuradio

In the flow diagram I have shared below, I want to divide the broadcast in 6MHz bandwidth into 2MHz parts and send it from 3 different PUB because i can't send 6MHz IQ file with ZMQ. I'm trying to listen to 88.4MHz in the bottom block. Transition bandwidth is 44100 KHz on bottom block filter and others are 2MHz. I can't get a proper result in this flow diagram, in general, the recording seems to be very fast. Is my mistake in the flow diagram or in the values I use?
[flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLLrO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Likely your sample rate isn't quite matching up. Try to downsample your signal with a rational resampler to take it from the 2MHz sample rate to 44.1kHz.

Comment: I changed the decimation value to 5 and sink's sample rate to 48KHz but still playing fast.